# Why wont ubuntu boot and install?

Tags: boot

I have created a bootable disk with ubuntu 15.10 and followed the instructions on ubuntu.com. But when I boot it, it takes me all the way to the screen asking if i want to "try ubuntu" or "install ubuntu". When it gets to this screen about 15 seconds in it will reset my entire computer back to the main BIOS screen.

I do not have any other operating system so until i fix this my $500 computer is useless.

I have tried :
1) using a usb flash drive
2) both 32bit and 64bit
3) removing my hard drive and booting (same problem)
3) removing my cd after download( gives me a error saying like no boot available, basicaly not downloading it)

Any sugestions would be great, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to select "Install Ubuntu" with the arrow keys. It will boot into Ubuntu, and eventually it will bring up the Install prompt and you can select your settings. (Don't mess with your partitions, Ubuntu may look nice but it is made of super complicated codes for newbies.)
Or select "Try Ubuntu" and take a look around it, when you're ready or you want to do, open the "Install Ubuntu x.xx or xx.xx" and the same install prompt appears for you to install Ubuntu.

Comment: I know how to do it, but when i hit "instsll ubuntu" it takes me all the way to the settings parts, and after i select my location the acreen goes black and it resets my computer.

Comment: Try downloading another ISO, don't worry it won't take 2 days with pendrive linux's "Universal USB Installer".